# How to fix "authz.dll is corrupt" error?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, dll

I've got a Vista x64 box here that throws an error about "authz.dll is corrupt" whenever I start an application.  Doesn't seem to hurt the function of the applications, but is very annoying.

So far I did:

- Malware & AV scans (nothing of note found)
- chkdsk/f (which failed to auto start on boot, had to force safe mode manually to make it run) which found no errors.
- sfc/scannow which reported back that errors were found, but it was unable to fix them.  It pointed me at a log file that was many MiB of what looked like GUIDs (totally unhelpful).

If I had another Vista x64 box laying around, I'd just try and replace authz.dll with another copy, but unfortunately I do not.  Googling comes up with a ton of hits that look like scammer sites and none that feel legit.

I don't know when it started as the owner didn't even know it was an issue.  Reports were just that "it crashes a lot" (RAM needed reseating, was only detecting all chips about every tenth boot).  So, not sure where to even start if I need a system restore.  Might be so far back that it wouldn't work anyways.

Any tried and true methods for fixing this obnoxious authz.dll popup?

Comment: You will need a Vista install Disk and use that along with SFC to fix the corruption, your WinSXS is corrupt, so it might be also easier to just reinatall windows or upgrade to 7 to fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still a bit of a mystery, but the problem no longer exists so I figured I'd better document it in case someone else has a similar problem (and to close it).

I found instructions at http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/42776-extract-files-windows-7-installation-dvd.html regarding how to extract DLLs from the original DVDs for Windows 7.  I operated under the assumption that Vista would probably be, if not the same, very close.  I was able to locate a Vista install DVD of the appropriate level.  I extracted the main file, parsed the XML, found that my index is "3" for Home Premium (the user's licensed level) and then extracted the authz.dll files into a pair of folders (since I need the 32 AND 64 bit versions based on the errors I'd been seeing).

At this point I suddenly realized that nowhere in this process had I seen the authz.dll warnings...  Thinking back, I had not seen them since setting 7-ZIP as the default for extraction on all items (3rd task in the linked instructions).  Full shutdown/reboot and the machine is functioning perfectly.  I did set aside the extracted DLLs in case it decides to act up again.  I don't see how the simple act of installing 7-Zip and setting it as default extractor could possibly have fixed it, but that's definitely when the problem disappeared.  FWIW, YMMV, etc!

Comment: By installing 7-zip you solved the corruption issue.  Its complicated and outside of the scope of this question.